# Simple question about group action on Pullbacks in the quotient stack $[X/G]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-group, algebraic-stacks

Consider the quotient stack $[X/G]$. Suppose $f: S' \to S$ morphism and $(E \to X, E \to S)$ is an object in $[X/G]$. Now we base change along $f$, and get $(f^*E :=E \times_S S' \to E, E \times_S S' \to S')$. Assume that $G$ acts on $E \times_S S'$ by acting only on the 1st factor.

We focus in particular on the morphism $E \times_S S' \to E$ and want to show that it is $G$-equivariant. (Since $E \to X$ is $G$-equivariant, then the composition of the two morphisms will yield that $E \times_S S' \to X$ is $G$-equivariant).

Question: 'Since $G$ acts trivially on $S'$, then $E \times_S S' \to E$ is $G$-equivariant'. Why is this statement true?

-Then one can regard $\alpha: E \to E$ as the morphism $E \times_S S' \to E$ (since $G$ acts trivially on $S'$). Then why would $\alpha(e \cdot g) = \alpha(e) \cdot g$?

-'Counter-example' : $e_1 \cdot g = e_2, e_2 \cdot g = e_1$ and  $\alpha(e_1) = e_1, \alpha(e_2) = e_1$. Then, $\alpha(e_1 \cdot g ) = e_1 \neq e_2 = \alpha(e_1) \cdot g$

Comment: look at the T points it is very easy to see that the morphism between them is equivariant

Comment: @ali When I consider $$\begin{matrix}
G(T) \times (E(T) \times_{S(T)} S'(T))&\xrightarrow{1_G \times \alpha}&G(T) \times E(T)\\
\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\cdot g \times 1_{S'}}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle\cdot g}\\
E(T) \times_{S(T)} S'(T)&\xrightarrow{\alpha} &E(T)
\end{matrix} $$, I can kind of see why the diag would commute. Could you elaborate on your comment, from the T-points how it is easy to see it is equivariant?

Comment: @ali From my prev comment, it does come back to the same problem that when you do $\cdot g \circ \alpha$, why is that the same as $\alpha \circ \cdot g$? There is something I am missing about the morphism $E \times_S S' \to^{\alpha} E$.

Comment: By yoneda lemma if you want to check the equality of two functions it is enough to check that for every T the functions induced on T point are equal. For that In the diagram you draw you can chase a point and see that digram is comutative

Comment: $\alpha$ is projection on first factor

Comment: @ali For a morphism $f: S' \to S$, in a cartesian diagram $$\begin{matrix}
E \times_{S} S'&\xrightarrow{\alpha}&E\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle G-Torsor}\\
S'&\xrightarrow{f} &S
\end{matrix} $$ , is $\alpha$ always the projection on 1st factor and the other down arrow the projection on 2nd factor?

Comment: @ali thanks for your comments, I will explicit what you said on the T points for practice: by Yoneda, $E(E\times_S S') \cong Hom(h_{E\times_S S'},h_E)$ as sets. For two functions $f,g: E\times_S S'\to E$, to show they are equal, it is enough to check that $\forall T,$ the functions induced on T points $h_{E\times_S S'}(T)\to h_E(T)$ are equal i.e. $(T \to^\beta E \times_S S') \mapsto (T \to^\beta E \times_S S'\to^f E)$ and $(T \to^\beta E \times_S S') \mapsto (T \to^\beta E \times_S S'\to^g E)$ are equal. Is this correct? What is the intuition of looking a T points here. Is it easier to check?

Comment: @ali Thanks, if $\alpha$ is the first projection, then by directly looking at the equality of two functions or by Yoneda lemma to their resp T points, the diag commutes! Could you answer the intuition of looking at the T points point of view?

Comment: it doesn't matter much in this case but usually it is easier to look at the points because they are sets and we understand sets better